# Linking error when building OpenGL app on Mac with command line

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I am new to building command line on Mac. While working on a cross-platform app using OpenGL, IMGui, and GLFW, I keep getting linking errors:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__glfwCreateContextEGL", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libGLFW.a(cocoa_window.o)
  "__glfwCreateContextNSGL", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libGLFW.a(cocoa_window.o)
  "__glfwCreateContextOSMesa", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libGLFW.a(cocoa_window.o)
  "__glfwInitEGL", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libGLFW.a(cocoa_window.o)
  "__glfwInitNSGL", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libGLFW.a(cocoa_window.o)
  "__glfwInitOSMesa", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libGLFW.a(cocoa_window.o)
  "__glfwPlatformCreateMutex", referenced from:
      _glfwInit in libGLFW.a(init.o)
  "__glfwPlatformCreateTls", referenced from:
      _glfwInit in libGLFW.a(init.o)
  "__glfwPlatformDestroyMutex", referenced from:
      _terminate in libGLFW.a(init.o)
  "__glfwPlatformDestroyTls", referenced from:
      _terminate in libGLFW.a(init.o)
  "__glfwPlatformGetTls", referenced from:
      _glfwDestroyWindow in libGLFW.a(window.o)
      __glfwRefreshContextAttribs in libGLFW.a(context.o)
      _glfwMakeContextCurrent in libGLFW.a(context.o)
      _glfwExtensionSupported in libGLFW.a(context.o)
      _glfwGetCurrentContext in libGLFW.a(context.o)
      _glfwSwapInterval in libGLFW.a(context.o)
      _glfwGetProcAddress in libGLFW.a(context.o)
      ...
  "__glfwPlatformLockMutex", referenced from:
      __glfwInputError in libGLFW.a(init.o)
  "__glfwPlatformSetTls", referenced from:
      __glfwInputError in libGLFW.a(init.o)
      _glfwInit in libGLFW.a(init.o)
  "__glfwPlatformUnlockMutex", referenced from:
      __glfwInputError in libGLFW.a(init.o)
  "__glfwTerminateNSGL", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in libGLFW.a(cocoa_init.o)
  "__glfwUpdateDisplayLinkDisplayNSGL", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidChangeScreen:] in libGLFW.a(cocoa_window.o)
```

I am linking to the Cocoa, CoreVideo, and IOKit frameworks. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I stumbled into the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I haven't been able to yet. Admittedly, though, I haven't really tried lately. I've just been working on continuing the project on Windows until I can get a chance to poke at it again.

Answer (score 0):

Hello might have found your error while doing something similar you forgot to link it to  a few libs that are required...

"g++ -o test main.c libGLEW.a libglfw3.a   -framework opengl -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit"

source: [https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glfw-howto/](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Esugih/courses/eecs487/glfw-howto/)

Comment: I have tried this solution, but I still get the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to you when trying to build GLFW on my own. It seems as though when building GLFW you're not including all files needed.

The following macOS-specific files are needed in the current version of GLFW when building:

```
src/cocoa_init.m
src/cocoa_joystick.m
src/cocoa_monitor.m
src/cocoa_window.m
src/cocoa_time.c
src/posix_thread.c
src/nsgl_context.m
src/egl_context.c
src/osmesa_context.c
src/posix_module.c
```

For you specifically, make sure `egl_context.c`,
`nsgl_context.m`, and
`posix_thread.c` are included.